# How to identify a specific location in returned Json through a postman test

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, javascript, api-testing, postman

When submitting an order to an API we get a Json response containing:

```
"AMLResults": [
    {
        "amlResult": [
            {
                "addresses": [
                    {
                        "flatNo": "Flat 1",
                        "houseNumber": "32",
                        "line1": "Ayr Street",
                        "line2": "",
                        "town": "GLASGOW",
                        "postcode": "G21 4DG"
                    }
```

And then I'm trying to test that the address is returned and formatted correctly

```
let amlResult = {};
pm.test("response should contain a formated client address",function(){
jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(amlResult).to.have.property('addresses');
addresses = amlResult.addresses;
    pm.expect(addresses).to.have.property('flatNo', 'Flat 1');
    pm.expect(addresses).to.have.property('houseNumber', '32');
    pm.expect(addresses).to.have.property('line1', 'Ayr Street');
    pm.expect(addresses).to.have.property('line2', '');
    pm.expect(addresses).to.have.property('town', 'GLASGOW');
    pm.expect(addresses).to.have.property('postcode', 'G21 4DG');
});
```

However I keep getting the following failure response:

```
response should contain a formated client address | AssertionError: expected {} to have property 'addresses'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, at

```
pm.expect(amlResult).to.have.property('addresses')
```

amlResult is an empty object, defined outside the test.

You may want something like this:

```
const firstAmlResult = jsonData.AMLResults[0];
pm.expect(firstAmlResult).to.have.property('amlResult');
```

Now you can inspect this AML Result object:

```
const result = firstAmlResult.amlResult[0]
pm.expect(result).to.have.property('addresses')

const address = result.addresses[0]
pm.expect(address ).to.have.property('flatNo')
pm.expect(result).to.have.property('flatNo')
pm.expect(result.flatNo).to.eql('Flat 1')
....
```

However, for all `to.have.property` checks, a better approach would be a Schema Validation. Tip #4 of [this blog post](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/07/28/api-testing-tips-from-a-postman-professional/) explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Validating by JSON Path Match:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.test("Check for house number", function () {
    pm.expect(jsonData.AMLResults[0].amlResult[0].addresses[0].houseNumber).to.eql(32);
});
```

You can also use an array find function.

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var result = jsonData.find(x =>x.AMLResults.amlResult.addresses.flatNo ==="Flat 1");
pm.environment.set("houseNumber", result.houseNumber);
```

You'll look for the object where flatNo is "Flat 1"
Store the other values like houseNumber in a variable of set it as an environment variable.

So you can validate their value:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.test("Check if houseNumber is correct", function () {
    var houseNumber = pm.environment.get("houseNumber "); 
    pm.expect(houseNumber ).to.eql(32);
});
```